# There isn't boot with Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I installed Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS in my PC in December, 2011. It was working good, but yesterday when I turn on the PC, I see a black screen with the following messages.

---

A group of numbers and at the end of numbers, the word "killed" and after:

```
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory  
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory  
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init
No init found. Try passing int=bootarg

BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
```

---

With a Live CD of Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS I start the PC and it is OK. 
When I try to see my Filesystem in my hard drive (Seagate 120 GB) I see the next message:

---

```
Unable to mount 115 Gb Filesystem
DBus error org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.Failed:
An operation is already pending
```

---

When I try to turn off the system, it can not finish and start again the process to load the Ubuntu system and finally I need to turn off the system manually.

I only remember 2 energy break downs (power outages) the day before the failure.
I do not know if the hard disk is damaged or if is possible to recover the system.

How can I recover my system or at least recover my files because I can not access the filesystem?

Comment: Make use of the ` letter to format error messages! (I don't want to bother moderators for such a minor issure). Basically the idiom is `my text`. (same as _italic_ or **bold**).

Comment: Also. This is LTS 'stable' right? I am thinking that. Perhaps this is a hardware issue. F.e. I had a LG laptop before in which the hardware was so crappy that it never should have gooten into sales. (I hate LG laptops since then. cheap though).

Comment: So. What is your computer. Does googleing for that model shows any other users having similar problems?

Comment: 'There is not booting'. Bad english. Will keep many rejecting reading your qw. Consider changing.

Comment: Is this a dual boot machine?

Answer (score 1):

This is a MAJOR stab in the dark.  I googled: Ubuntu DBus error

```
org.gtk.Private.RemoteVolumeMonitor.Failed: An operation is already pending
```

I found this: http://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+question/150669 (look for delance's answer).

This video may also help as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6IVZip6EkU - watch the video and don't reload Ubuntu (he says he panicked and should have used the live cd first).

Comment: @crzcas - check the youtube video. It looks pretty good.

Comment: MAJOR stabs in the dark. Sure like those.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try deleting this file described [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7298991).

Comment: Thank you skub but the problem is that I do not have access to the hard drive to see or delete some file.